# Where should be placed classes with long living connections in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Right now I am using a class with socket as a property, but I would like to know how to handle this case in a better way. The class is registered as singleton in DI and the `Connect` method on the socket is called in the constructor.

Comment: Depends on a lot of other factors - thread safety, reconnect, ...  Why do you need a socket in the first place?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I can guess maybe he needs real-time data communication (push service) from a legacy system that only supports socket and not SignalR, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## You can use an `IHostedService`

They were designed as the primary means to run long running tasks in the background.

Basically what you need to do is create a class that holds your connections, implementing `IHostedService`. (If you are .NET Core 2.1+ you can do that easily by deriving from `BackgroundService` and overriding `ExecuteAsync`.

Then you simply register your class as a singleton at startup (`services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, YourHostedService>()`), and the framework will automatically recognize it and manage starting & stopping for you.

There are two a few great advantages of this:

1. You don't have to worry (that much) about threading, the host will handle scheduling your task.
2. The framework will handle startup and graceful shutdown for you. It all works the way you already know: Using a `CancellationToken` with a configurable timeout.
3. As the class is registered as a regular singleton via the IoC container, you can access it via DI just like any other class. (Of course then you need to register it using another interface as well not just as an `IHostedService`). This allows you to call methods on your socket-manager from your controllers, etc.

Here are my two go to tutorials on hosted services, but you can find others as well:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice

Answer (score 0):

One good technique would be to create an extension method such as `UseMySocket` targeting the `IWebHostBuilder` type. You can use this in the `CreateWebHostBuilder` method of your `Program` class. Keep in mind that you have to implement it in a way that does not block the current thread. For example:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseMySocket()
.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Another technique would be to create a singleton type for the socket followed by instantiating it and injecting it into the service collection in the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` class.